# Apache2.4 on Centos - allow specific IPs to skip authentication - not working

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I followed [this official guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html#authz) to replace my code that was working fine on Apache2.2.
My goal here is to require authentication for everything that's under /var/www (all websites) but bypass that for some specific IPs.
I edited my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file as follows, but although I can  pass the authentication using user & password - it always asks me to do so, even from the IPs on the list:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    #Require all granted

    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /path/to/the/htpasswd/file
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require ip 2.3.4.5
    Require ip 3.4.5.6
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

---

Any idea?

Comment: What do your Apache error/log files say?

Comment: No new logs since I did that...  (Maybe I wasn't clear: I can pass the authentication with user & password, but I have to do that from every IP, even the ones from the list)

Comment: Perhaps you still have some old 2.2 directives somewhere that are taking precedence. Try configuring apache to not load module `mod_access_compat` and it might complain about those old directives. You can add an explicit `<RequireAny>` around the requires, though it shouldnt be needed.

Comment: @meuh I tried also with <RequireAny> but I understood that it's not necessary after I read the docs & removed it (it didn't work either way)

Comment: @meuh Thank you so much! I found another directive that was overriding it & now it works perfectly!